# Call a generated .dll file from codegen matlab in c program

Tags: c, matlab, dll, codegen

I am using `codegen` in MATLAB R2016b to generate a .dll file as follows:

```
codegen -config:dll ex_fun.m -args {0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

I have tried to include the dll file as a reference using Visual Studio 2015 but nothing works fine and I couldn't use the .lib file as a linker eitherll.

The strange thing is that I could easily use `gcc` on Linux by compiling the .c script that calls the C function along with the output .so file (which is equivalent to .dll in windows) as follows:

```
gcc main.c ex_fun.so -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

However, I couldn't find any direct method in Windows. How can I use and call a .dll file output by MATLAB in a C main script program?

It should be noted that a .def file is also generated but I don't how to use it along with the output dll file.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio IDE:

- Switch platform to **"x64"**

In Project properties:

- C++>General>Additional include directories = ^add compilation folder.
- Linker>General>Additional libraries directories = ^add compilation
  folder.
- Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies = "ex_fun.lib"
- In code: add  `#include "ex_fun.h"`
- After compilation, copy the "ex_fun.dll" to output folder and run.

Comment: I have tried your suggested steps. However, I am having this error message:

LNK1190 invalid fixup found, type 0x0014 ex_fun C:\Users\LAB\Desktop\test_ex_fun\ex_fun\ex_fun\ex_fun.lib(ex_fun.obj)

Comment: By the way, I am using visual studio 2015

Comment: No. for the32 bit platform, I am rather having this error for all the .h files :

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ex_fun

Comment: And I am having this warning : LNK4272 library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Comment: By the way, I am following up the steps in this link : https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/using-a-matlab-coder-dynamic-library-in-a-simple-microsoft-visual-studio-project.html?searchHighlight=Use%20a%20C%20Dynamic%20Library%20in%20a%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Project&s_tid=doc_srchtitle.

However, I am having the error of LNK1190 as previously mentioned.

I hope this might help you

Comment: I have contacted the mathworks team and they have replied that they assume that the compiler used for code generation is visual studio. However When I tried to setup this compiler on matlab using mex -setup, I had this error:No supported compiler or SDK was found although the visual studio c++ compiler is installed from visual studio 2015

Comment: my problem is solved by install the visual studio SDK using this url:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683786.aspx.
Then apply mex -setup on matlab command window and thus, it should be indicated that MEX is configured to microsoft visual c++ 2015. Then by applying the steps mentioned by Mendi Barel or even mentioned in https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/using-a-matlab-coder-dynamic-library-in-a-simple-microsoft-visual-studio-project.html?searchHighlight=Use%20a%20C%20Dynamic%20Library%20in%20a%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Project&s_tid=doc_srchtitle, the problem is solved.